# Current Menu Item changes the container <div> background image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So this might get a bit confusing, but basically I'm trying to get the current page/menu item to change the parent div's background image. The trick is, some menu items are listed under multiple tabs, so I'm trying to distinguish which menu item was clicked on once the page loads.

Here is an example I quickly threw together: http://jsfiddle.net/r6r7U/

So in this example, when the page loads, I would want to change the background image of the div with the class "changing-background" depending on which menu/sub-menu item was clicked. However, as you can see, the 'Golden Retriever' hyperlink is stored under two separate menu items.

I was thinking of using the following in some manner:

```
.hasClass('current-menu-item')
```

I'm sure this question is very confusing, but basically I'm not sure how to do this in either CSS or Jquery since my background is the first thing that is loading on the page.

Comment: Well f.e. you could simply place the background image to use as a custom data attribute on each menu item, `data-bg-img="foo.jpg"` or something – and then you just get the content of that attribute from the current menu item and set the background image for your div element … more sophisticated approaches are possible, but as a start this should do fine.

Answer (score 0):

If this is 
`navigation menu`
you will have to mark on what page you are at the moment, for example with .active class:

http://jsfiddle.net/r6r7U/4/

so when page is loaded, its already marked in html with active class. Ul elements have id, each ul has its own background color

Here's solution in case you are using something like 
`jquery tabs`
http://jsfiddle.net/r6r7U/12/